# How can I use loop index in an attribute?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm new to Vue, and can't achieve quite a simple thing. I want to be able to use the loop index to set a unique name for an attribute. For example, I want to set the ID attribute to something like this: id="somename{{index}}", but that gives an interpolation inside attributes error.

```
<div v-for="(dt, index) in driveTrain" >
    <input type="radio" id="driveTrain-{{index}}" >
    <label for="driveTrain-{{index}}">{{dt}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind the id dynamically using `v-bind` directly:

```html
<div v-for="(dt, index) in driveTrain" >
    <input type="radio" :id="'driveTrain'+index">
    <label :id="'driveTrain'+index">{{dt}}</label>
</div>
```

**Or:**

bind it using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```html
 <div v-for="(dt, index) in driveTrain" >
        <input type="radio" :id="`driveTrain${index}`">
        <label :id="`driveTrain${index}`">{{dt}}</label>
    </div>
```